# css media query adding class to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-iconname" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>Link Name</a></li>
```

I am then using this media query in my CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    ...
}
```

how can i change my  tag to:

```
<i class="fa fa-iconname lg-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
```

when the media query takes effect?

Answer (score 17):

You can use pure css to achieve this by just replicating the list-item and toggle with media query like this:

HTML:

```
<li class="bigScreen"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-iconname"></i>Link Name</a></li>

<li class="smallScreen"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-iconname lg-2x"></i>Link Name</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .bigScreen {
    display:none;
  }
  .smallScreen {
    display:block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  .bigScreen {
    display:block;
  }
  .smallScreen {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  It is a bad idea to use JS resize function because the resize has bugs in many browsers.  I have seen several cases of resize fails to fire based on grabbing the corner of the window, or bottom edge, etc.  But using two classes `bigScreen` and `smallScreen` is super versatile for many things.

Comment: Maintenance wise this is not a very nice solution. If you're in need to do this more often you'll end up with all sorts of elements having been copy/pasted, which easily leads to mistakes when maintaining the code a few months or even years later. The JavaScript approach is more complex but isn't duplicating code.

Answer (score 12):

CSS is just a styling language, it cannot actually edit the HTML.

If you want to actually make changes to the HTML, use javascript:

jQuery:

```
var $homeIcon = $('.fa-iconname');

$(window).resize(function() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) $homeIcon.addClass('lg-2x');
  else $homeIcon.removeClass('lg-2x');
});
```

*[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9y1p42Lq/)*

Vanilla JS:

```
var homeIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-home');

window.onResize = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) homeIcon.classList.add('lg-2x');
  else homeIcon.classList.remove('lg-2x');
};
```

*[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jf2hyjx5/)*

Comment: You can toggle class "lg-2x" if it is not there then add that .

Comment: It is quicker , but in long term toggle class is good , when ever we need to add the class. Whereas i like your answer simple and easy to implement .good job !

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that with css, but you can with JavaScript or jQuery.

fa-2x is essentialy: `font-size: 2em;` . So, you can do this:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .fa-iconname {
    font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle class lg-2x on element li when the window size is less than 1000px .

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() <=1000) {
        $('i').toggleClass(function() {
           if ( $( this ).is( ".lg-2x" ) ) {
               console.log("class already there good to go");
           } else {
              $( this ).addClass("lg-2x");
           }
        }
    }else{
           $('i').removeClass("lg-2x");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an equivalent class for bigger screen and leave it empty:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .lg-2x {
        /* empty class */
    }
}
```

and assign it to the html element from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class identified as a class whose name indicates it is affected by media queries: media-lg-2x{}

```
 .media-lg-2x{}
 @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .media-lg-2x {
    font-size: 1em;
    }
 } 
 @media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .media-lg-2x {
    font-size: 2em;
    }
 }
```

I prefer to keep content confined to a single instance, and deal with display issues in code.