# How to change the image components according to the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a study case:

I have an image wrapped in an intro `div` for the desktop size like this:

```
<div class="intro">
            <img id="gambar" src="assets/images/image-intro-desktop.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
```

then when entering the mobile file size the `img` tag will change to:

```
<img id="gambar" src="assets/images/image-intro-mobile.jpg" alt="">
```

So the question is how do I change the component, what js code should I use??

Comment: You can use the same concept from this other thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594124/4114907 except you can switch the image `src` instead of an element `class`..

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using css

```
<style>
  .intro{
    content:url("assets/images/image-intro-desktop.jpg");
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .intro{
       content:url("assets/images/image-intro-mobile.jpg");
    }
  }
  </style>

  <img class="intro"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add two event listeners for the `resize` and `load` events, check the window width if it's smaller than your desired breakpoint to change the image source. Otherwise reset the source back to the original.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'resize', changeImageSrc() );
document.addEventListener( 'load', changeImageSrc() );


function changeImageSrc() {
  var init_img_src = document.getElementById('gambar').src;
  
  // Change 600 to your breakpoint
  if( window.innerWidth < 600 ) {
    document.getElementById('gambar').src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/250';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('gambar').src = init_img_src;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <img id="gambar" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for Javascript code so:

Maybe you can run this in a `window.onload`. Depends on what you want.

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  // returns true if its a mobile
  // change src here
  document.getElementById('gambar').src = "assets/images/image-intro-mobile.jpg";
}else{
  // returns false if it isn't
}
```